# Recommend desktop search software?

Tags: windows-7, desktop-search

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What's the fastest desktop search tools you've used on Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/8654/whats-the-fastest-desktop-search-tools-youve-used-on-windows)
>   [What's a good alternative to Windows' “Search for Files and Folders”?](https://superuser.com/questions/135423/whats-a-good-alternative-to-windows-search-for-files-and-folders)

Google Desktop Search does not allow us specify the index file folders path.

Is there any other better alternatives to Google Desktop Search.

PS: I'm using Windows 7.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See also :

[Everything search engine](http://www.voidtools.com/)
Ultra-fast, but search on file names only

[Agent Ransack 2010](http://www.mythicsoft.com/page.aspx?type=agentransack&page=home)
File names and contents, but no index.

Answer (score 0):

The built in [Windows search](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/features/windows-search) is pretty full-featured and allows user control over indexed directories and it is a default component of Windows. Is there a reason that you're not using that?

Comment: It does not support content-search.

Comment: @Jichao - If there is a specific feature that you are looking for, it would be helpful to post it in your question. We're not mind readers.

Comment: @Jichao I am using Windows 7 Search. It is not a default options, but you can configure it to perform content search. I often search for keywords in my PDFs using Windows Search.

Answer (score 0):

I think copernic desktop search is great: http://www.copernic.com/en/products/desktop-search/index.html

There's a free version for private/non-commercial use.

Comment: I find CDS to be a resource hog. I've used it on and off. I always uninstall due to how poorly it manages itself amongst other applications that run.

Comment: CDS is not free anymore except for a limited amount of file types (MS Word and Excel NOT INCLUDED)